# How to assign console output as value to some variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, stdout

I want to assign content printed on console as a value in variable in next line in my code.
Is this possible with $stdout ?

say for example I am printing one unpacked array value on console.
Now I want to use this printed value as value of variable coming on next line of my code.
for example `puts "\nPageSize:\n#{c1}\n"` prints 7117 which is a single element array.Now I want to assign this printed value as an integer to some variable x in next line of code below this `puts "\nPageSize:\n#{c1}\n"`.

Comment: You should really start reading a basic introduction to Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In IRB you can use a special underscore variable to get the result of the last expression:

```
> 2 + 2
> x = _
> 4
```

But since 'puts' returns nil, it won't work. If you avoid puts, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You normally cannot read back what you wrote to stdout. You *could* monkey-patch `puts` or `IO` to achieve that -- but I guess this is not what you want to do.

If you can print the value, you can as well assign it to a variable (in fact it is already stored in `c1[0]`):

```
puts "\nPageSize:\n#{c1}\n"
x = c1[0] # or c1.first
```

or better

```
x = c1[0] # or c1.first
puts "\nPageSize:\n#{x}\n"
```

What the `#{c1}` part in the interpolated string does is invoking `c1`'s `to_s` to convert it to a `String` and inserting that `String`. So it converts the `[7117]` to `"7117"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign like this ...........

intilize variable first of type integer

```
   x = 0
```

then assign as

```
   x = c1

   or

   x = arr[0]
```

Or as you wants.........

But puts return nothing so you can't assign printed value to some variable.Rather than you

use some variable and assign its value to another variable.